# Why do I get "You have an error in your SQL Syntax" when I pass parameters into MySqlParameter?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql

I am getting following exception with my code

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''MachineSimulator'' 

var sqlParams = new[]
                                            {
                                                new MySqlParameter("@MachineSimulatorDb",GlobalVariables.MachineSimulatorDb),
                                                new MySqlParameter("@CAMXMassagesTable" ,GlobalVariables.CamxmassagesTable)
                                            };

            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(GlobalVariables.ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using(var command = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = conn;
                    command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);

                    command.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS @MachineSimulatorDb;";

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }


            }
```

Any idea what is wrong there ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL probably doesn't allow you to pass a parameter to `create database`.  Try:

```
command.CommandText = string.Format("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `{0}`",  
    GlobalVariables.MachineSimulatorDb);
```

If the variables you use come from an usafe source, you should be aware of the danger of SQL Injection.

Comment: ", if I try USE @MachineSimulatorDb;"; I have the same exception. so it is not he problem .

Comment: @Night Walker: More likely, `use` does not allow parameters either.  In general parameters are allowed for values, not to specify database objects.  So `where id = @MyParameter` will work, but `select * from @MyTable` will not.

Answer (score 0):

When I used MySqlParameter, it was working with a ? character, not with the @ character. This might your problem here; eg:

```
new MySqlParameter("?MachineSimulatorDb");
```

But Andomar is probably correct that you can't use a MySqlParameter to feed the name of the new database.